# C# Class Typing with parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I have c# class that take type parameters

```
 public abstract class Repository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType>
    : IUnitOfWorkRepository
    where TDomainType
    : IAggregateRoot
    where TDatabaseType : class
```

this base class i want actually us in normal and security sections of my applications, and for the sake of not repeating code I would like to do something like this:

```
 public class PmRepository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType> : Repository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**
Sorry didnt the error I am  getting as I thought there was problem doing this.

The error I am getting is this

```
The type 'TDatabaseType' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TDatabaseType' in the generic type or method 'Repository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType>'
```

and

```
The type 'TDomainType' cannot be used as type parameter 'TDomainType' in the generic type or method 'Repository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TDomainType' to 'ThunderCat.Core.Domain.IAggregateRoot'.
```

Comment: That code should technically work...I don't get what you're asking.

Comment: As @CodingMadeEasy this code is perfectly fine as is  (to get exact sample to compile `PmRepository` need to be abstract too, but it is unlikely problem...) - please clarify.

Comment: Is TDatabaseType a struct?

Comment: But is the `Type` a `Class` or a `Struct`?  A `Class` is a Reference Type and a `Struct` is a Value Type.  This is what your first error message appears to be referring to, or it may be referring to generic type constraints.  Are they on the base class?

Comment: you have tu pute the where clause in all derived classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inheriting class needs the same constraints as the superclass:

```
public class PmRepository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType>
    : Repository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType>
    where TDomainType : IAggregateRoot
    where TDatabaseType : class
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the constraints to the new class as well:

```
where TDomainType : IAggregateRoot
where TDatabaseType : class

public class PmRepository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType> : Repository<TDomainType, TIdType, TDatabaseType>
    where TDomainType : IAggregateRoot
    where TDatabaseType : class
```

If the new class will not have those constraints then you could access the base class using the inherited class without the restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

There is another example in Microsoft's official website for C#.

See here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types][1]

```
public class PointFactory(int numberOfPoints)
{
    public IEnumerable<Point> CreatePoints()
    {
        var generator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
        {
            yield return new Point(generator.Next(), generator.Next());
        }
    }
}
```